# Consuming a REST 2 Dimensional String Array

Tags: rest, form-parameter

I have a `POST` in this format:

> offset:"0"
>   sort[0][field]:"lname"
>   sort[0][direction]:"desc"

How do I set up the REST consumer? I have tried this but it only returns a `NULL` for the sort parameter.

```
@Path("/test")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response command(
    @FormParam("offset") Integer offset,
    @FormParam("sort") List<sortstuff> sort) { ...
```

Comment: I assume this is a Java framework you're using for the REST server? You should clarify by tagging it with the correct one.

Comment: The answer is quite simple. Each parameter is a form parameter. Hence, sort[0][field] is a parameter name.